# mysql-server:Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox. I try install mysql-server using command
sudo apt-get install mysql-server, i always got error like below:

```
Some packages could be installed .This may mean that you have 
request an impossible  situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysqsl-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and then i try use some command like below :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but it still error. Please help me!

Comment: This question should be moved to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This can repair broken packages or purge the installation.

If mysql-server is not installed with -f , you can try to install with normal way

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y
```